# Unable to install NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10 - "Fatal Error by Java Runtime Environment"

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10, fatal-error, netbeans-8

I am trying to install the latest version of NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10. I have jdk1.8.0_111 and jre1.8.0_111 installed with all the path variables set. Got the latest NVIDIA Graphics driver installed for GTX 730. But still, when i try to install NetBeans, it gives a "Fatal Error by Java Runtime Environment"

Paste Bin [Link for Error file](http://pastebin.com/U4HKV1R7)

Comment: its a AccessViolation exception, try to install to a path in "My Documents" and run the installer as an Admin

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was that my God Mode folder was on the Desktop. When I deleted it, then there was no error in installation. The God Mode folder should be moved from the C: directory.

Comment: Please don't add *"Me too"* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).